# tailwind toggle component not passing value in form

Tags: checkbox, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add a toggle switch to my form (blade template in laravel 9). I pulled the toggle from https://flowbite.com/docs/forms/toggle/, but it was missing the 'name' attribute so I added that myself, and it now appears in the form data, but it's always null.

Here's the code:

```
<label class="relative inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="goal" value="" class="sr-only peer">
    <div class="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-blue-300 dark:peer-focus:ring-blue-800 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-600"></div>
    <span class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Goal</span>
</label>
```

As far as I can tell, the toggle switch doesn't actually change the value of the checkbox at all, but the div set to change based on 'peer' suggests that it is.

I must be missing something really obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I delete this embarrassing question somehow? It's been so long since I used a checkbox, I forgot how they work. I needed to add the value which is passed back when the toggle is switched.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="goal" value="goal" class="sr-only peer">
```